# Dynamic Column SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table in SQL with dynamic headings. I have the headings working just fine but I cannot figure out how to group the rows.

Example Data is

```
CriteriaID     KSB_Requirement        ModuleID    Module_Title
   1         Understand something       5         Principles 1
   1         Understand something       6         Principles 2 
   1         Understand something       7         Principles 3 
   2         Learn something            5         Principles 1
   2         Learn something            6         Principles 2
```

The result I get using:

```
DECLARE 
  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Module_Title) 
            FROM Standards_Coverage_Pivot_Data
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT KSB_Requirement, ' + @cols + ' from 
            Standards_Coverage_Pivot_Data 
            pivot 
            (
                Count(CriteriaID)
                for Module_Title in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
 execute(@query);
```

is....

```
KSB_Requirement       Principle 1    Principle 2    Principle 3
Understand something      1              0              0
Understand something      0              1              0
Understand something      0              0              1
Learn something           1              0              0
Learn something           0              1              0
```

What I really want to display is:

```
KSB_Requirement       Principle 1    Principle 2    Principle 3
Understand something      1              1              1
Learn something           1              1              0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there

```
DECLARE 
  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Module_Title) 
            FROM Standards_Coverage_Pivot_Data
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT * from (Select KSB_Requirement,Module_Title,CriteriaID From Standards_Coverage_Pivot_Data) s
            pivot 
            (
                Count(CriteriaID)
                for Module_Title in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
 execute(@query);
```

Returns

```
KSB_Requirement       Principles 1  Principles 2    Principles 3
Learn something       1             1               0
Understand something  1             1               1
```

Comment: @gillers322 Happy to help..  But let's be hones, you did the bulk of the work and you had a well structured question... thus the UpVote